# Installing support repository for Android Studio

Tags: android, linux, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio on Arch Linux and I installed the Support Repository using the SKD Manager. However whenever I try to use it I get an error saying:

```
Error:Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0] on root project 'Aaaa'.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
```

I tried appcompat v7, support v4 and support v13 (I checked all of them are installed). I tried running as root and I still get the same error. The path in local.properties is pointing to the right directory. I'm no really sure what else I should change.

I created a blank activity just to try and use this repository, here is the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've put your `dependencies` block in the wrong **build.gradle** file. Instead of the top-level build file, put it in your module's build file instead.